# Why is my try / except not giving any value for csv file?

Tags: python, csv, exception

I am limited to not use lists, using only the CSV library, use one loop and one `if` statement to parse through a txt file that has CSV data. I used the `if` statement to filter the rows for a specific job and that's why I used a `try` and `except` statements to find the average of those specific row and print it, but I can't seem to get a value.

Here's the code. OK here is the edit. the problem now is that the salary is a float so I can't use it for `sum()` — but am I on the right track?

here is the message i get in the output. i also fixed the indentation, i think it got missed up while editing.

```py
 File "C:/Users/USER1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 32, in <module>
    total_salaries = sum(salary)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

```
import csv

file = open('SP21-Emp1.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file)
total_salaries = 0
instructor_count = 0
print("Reading from file SP21-Emp1.txt" "\n")
for line in reader:
name, job, salary = line
salary = float(salary)
salary = salary + (salary*0.1)
instructor_count = len(line)
total_salaries = sum(salary)
if job == 'Instructor':
  first_name, last_name = name.split(' ', 1)
  print(f'Name: {last_name} {first_name} \t Job: {job} \t Income: {salary}',)

try:
    average_instructor_salary = total_salaries / instructor_count
except ValueError:
    print('can not calculate average because there were no instructor salaries found.')
    average_instructor_salary = "No instructor salary found"

print("\n" "The average of the instructors' salaries is:", average_instructor_salary)
```

Comment: Division by zero? ``instructor_count`` is ``0`` and your code never changes that.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: You're not adding anything to `total_salaries` or `instructor_count` in your loop

Comment: sorry, i don't know how i missed that, I'm confused as i am still new to python. as this isn't a list i tried `len()` and `sum()` but they don't work. so what do i add value to instructor_count and total_salaries? either way i will need some time to figure something out and get back to you guys with the edit

Comment: `sum()` will work fine with floats. I suggest you [edit] your question again and provide some sample input data so it's a [mre]. Note too that it looks like the indentation of the code in your question is wrong (specifically with the `for` loop).